# Linux: Mount a remote disk stored on a custom storage

Tags: filesystems, mount, remote, network-filesystem

We have a non-standard storage (FS) on which we have flat disk images stored. We need to extract data from this raw image on a different host. The word "extraction" here means that I want to copy selective files & folders. The storage server does expose API like read, write, seek, etc. I do not want to download the entire raw image locally and then mount. The FS on the flat disk images are can be NTFS, EXT2/3/4.

Is it possible to "fool" the Linux to read from a device/fs but infact its reading over the network (i.e. storage)?

I am exploring FUSE FS, but thought to ask to see if there are any better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Can you expose the root of the file system via NFS?

At that point it's simple to mount the individual image files as their native file system types and access the files they contain.

Comment: No, its a proprietary storage and proprietary File System. (Sorry for the delay in response)